# How does change inn internal IP of a instance doesn't cause connection disruption

Tags: google-cloud-platform

what am trying to get is when we delete an instance in GCP and create a new instance with same configurations (name, zone etc.) how does our other compute resources treat this just as an replacement of our old deleted instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS resolution and FQDN are the answer to it.

Each instance have a host name (it’s nothing but instance name) which could be resolved to a internal IP address
Each instance also have a FQDN (fully qualified domain name) for an instance which is in following formats

FQDN is [hostname].[zone].c.[project-id].internal

> Before deletion  :[hostname].[zone].c.[project-id].internal1
> After deletion   :[hostname].[zone].c.[project-id].internal2

DNS name always points to a specific instance no matter what internal IP address is. Each instance  has a metadata server which acts as a DNS resolver. As a result all your other compute resources will have seamless connectivity with the new instance